# Cannot install accelerate-cuda in Haskell

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

I am on a linux box and trying to experiment with Haskell's *Accelerate* library but having problems installing it. I have successfully installed the ***accelerate*** package but there seems to be a dependency problem, which I have detailed below.

```
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
accelerate-cuda-0.14.0.0 depends on haskell-src-exts-1.14.0.1 which failed to
install.
cuda-0.5.1.1 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
haskell-src-exts-1.14.0.1 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
haskell-src-meta-0.6.0.5 depends on haskell-src-exts-1.14.0.1 which failed to
install.
language-c-quote-0.7.6 depends on haskell-src-exts-1.14.0.1 which failed to
install.
```

I searched SO and noticed someone else had a similiar issue installed the *cuda* package, and was resolved by adding the cabal bin path to the PATH; I tried this but it didn't solve this problem.

Please could someone help as I really keen to play with this fantastic library.

Comment: IIRC, you'll need some sort of CUDA drivers to install some of the packages. It's a real bear to get installed, good luck!

Comment: Definitely try to install dependencies individually, that will help you find out which package is really causing the problem. I'm seeing cuda-0.5.1.1 appear, which makes me wonder if you have drivers.

Comment: Hi Eric, I have the cuda sdk install. I will try to install individually and see if that works. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: You need the SDK, but you also need CUDA-capable NVIDIA drivers. Honestly, I'm not sure I *ever* got that working in Linux.

Comment: 1) Ensure that your cabal db is up to date 2) Try installing haskell-src-exts package and show us log.

Comment: BTW this library is not that fantastic. Accelerate DSL is pretty limited (AFAIR, it was even impossible to implement AdditiveGroup instance for CUDA arrays), cuda backend performs stupid recompilation at every function call. And you can hardly extend this library, because its internals are tied into timber hitch.

Comment: Can you provide the reason given for why `haskell-src-exts` failed to install?  It should be earlier in the compilation output.  IIRC `haskell-src-exts` requires happy or alex which cabal will not install automatically.

Comment: @user2894391 I have made sure cabal is up-to-date using 'cabal update' and it installed haskell-src-exts successfully. I tried after installing it and it got further than it did previously but failed again. This time it is complaining about cannot find language-c-quote-0.7.6. It looks like I have to manually install :s

Comment: I have it installed now! Phew. I had to traverse the dependency chain and manually installed each one. Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: Well, accelerate requires older version. Congratulations, you've just fall into dependency hell. But you may try simple workaround: rename .cabal and .ghc directories somehow, then do 'cabal update', then try installing accelerate-cuda (not haskell-src-exts!). Or you may try cabal-dev instead.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to check **accelerate-examples** and play with them and I also didn't have **CUDA** GPU (AMD only) and that's how I eventually installed **accelerate-examples** with **stack**:

```
git clone https://github.com/AccelerateHS/accelerate-examples
cd accelerate-examples
#choose version:
ln stack-8.6.yaml stack.yaml
#build without CUDA targeting:
stack build --flag accelerate-examples:-llvm-ptx --flag accelerate-fft:-llvm-ptx
```

Installation will build all the examples and print the info regarding where they was put.
Might also need to specify GHC libs path with something like: **export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:~/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.6.5/lib/ghc-8.6.5/rts/**

Also checked that **accelerate** installs as well the same way but even without specifying any flags (I guess because it doesn't build any programs yet?), but examples are what's fun :)

P.S. You can move **llvm-ptx** flags to **stack.yaml** config: change **# flags: {}** line to:

```
flags:
  accelerate-fft:
    llvm-ptx: false
  accelerate-examples:
    llvm-ptx: false
```